# Confusion with chocolate bar problem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

> Given a $4\times 3$ chocolate cube, find the minimal number of divisions to break it into twelve $1\times 1$ cubes. **Hint.** The division process can be described by a graph. How many edges does this graph have?

I thought the reasoning is simple - any division process will take twelve steps because every division adds exactly one piece. But then, I don't understand why the analogous binary tree is relative, or how counting edges helps prove anything. What am I supposed to make of the hint?

Comment: Ignore the hint and do your thing, but avoid a small mistake - the answer is 11

Comment: "every division adds exactly one piece" - not quite. The first division changes the scene from one piece to two pieces, so it indeed adds exactly one piece. But in every division after that, you can stack up several pieces on top of each other, and double the previous amount "in a single shot".

Comment: It should just be eleven breaks because you start out with one piece already.

Comment: @barakmanos I don't think this problem allows stacking.

Comment: In any case, the above comments show that the question desperately needs a **definition of what a "division" means in the problem**.

Comment: I don't think the problem is sufficiently clear.

Comment: It seems, that if I have a knife of a proper shape, I can do it with one cut.